# Permission to select deployment area in Spotfire without administrator rights

Tags: tibco, spotfire

There is a Spotfire Server (7.0) with several deployment areas and users and I want to give permission to all these users to be able select the deployment area, when logging in into Spotfire Professional.

So far, I was able to solve this only by adding these users to the Administrator group, but another solution is needed, because I don't want these users to have administrator rights.

Is there a way to give permission to the users to be able to choose the deployment area, without giving administrator rights to these users?

Comment: What do you mean by areas? Library folders, or special functions / rights in Spotfire itself?

Comment: do you mean Deployment Areas? I don't see this as a separate license in the permissions, and I am sure this is an administrative action. what is your use case for giving regular users access to multiple deployment areas? maybe there's another way to accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: As far as library permissions go there should be 4 levels: View, Browse & View, R/W, and Full Control.

Comment: @niko: yes, deployment areas. the use case is that I have different packages deployed on different areas. for example I have development, test and production areas and i want developers and testers to be able to choose which area to use

Comment: @clesiemo3: This is not related to library permissions. Library permissions are already set correctly on the server, but I cannot find a proper way to manage these deployment areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users who have permissions to access multiple deployment areas have [the option to choose or pre-select a deployment area](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.0/doc/html/intro/intro_details_on_select_deployment_area.htm).

you can [assign a user group to a deployment area using the web console](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.0.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/assign_deployment_area_to_group.htm) (this assignment is not available in the Administration Manager):

1. access the Spotfire Server in your browser as you would to deploy a new package
2. go to the **Groups** tab
3. search for/select the group you'd like to assign (or create a new one)
4. click the **Assign Deployment Area...** button
5. choose the area and click OK

so, you can create two new groups "Dev" and "Test", assign access rights to each groups' respective deployment area, then add users to those groups.

I think users will need to [modify the server properties from the login screen](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/intro/intro_details_on_add_edit_server.htm) to choose the deployment area. it might be easier for them to have a separate entry for each deployment area on the server, that way they can choose from the combobox on the login screen.